# Wireless disabled and cannot scan any network in Ubuntu

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager

I installed both windows and Ubuntu in my laptop. There´s no problem with windows. I think I did some update on Ubuntu maybe and when I restarted there’s no wifi connection. I googled a lot and tried anything except update the driver since I don’t have a wired connection at home.
I tried rfkill unblock there’s not soft or hard block on the wireless. I checked network manager state and restarted it. But it didn’t work. Here is some of my information. I would appreciate it if someone can offer any help. Thx!

```
    $ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:c822]
    Subsystem: Electronics & Telecommunications RSH Device [1058:1e25]
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_pci
    Kernel modules: rtwpci
```

`$ rfkill list`

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`$ iwconfig`

```
docker0   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          
enx00e04c3601cd  no wireless extensions.
```

`$  sudo lshw -c network`

```
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 00
       serial: 40:23:43:d2:c9:3b
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtw_pci driverversion=5.4.0-51-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:59 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0700000-c070ffff

  *-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: docker0
       serial: 02:42:dc:2c:d7:08
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion=2.3 firmware=N/A ip=172.17.0.1 link=no multicast=yes

  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: enx00e04c3601cd
       serial: 00:e0:4c:36:01:cd
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.10.11 duplex=half link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
```

I have installed the new driver but the problem remains...

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:c822]
Subsystem: Electronics & Telecommunications RSH Device [1058:1e25]
Kernel driver in use: rtw_8822ce
Kernel modules: rtwpci, rtw_8822ce

$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
    # Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
version: 2
renderer: NetworkManager
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. You can copy and paste terminal output as text. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Please run `Software Updater` and get the newer -52 kernel, and see if that gets things working again. If not, edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: I have run update and upgrade and now have a kernel version 5.4.0-52-generic @heynnema

Comment: Good! Does wi-fi work now? Did you unblacklist the prior driver, and remove the driver that you installed?

Answer (score 0):

You have an RTL8822CE device that is not supported out of the box yet.

Get an internet connection by other means, e.g a phone connected to USB and install a driver this way:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
sudo dkms add ./rtw88
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

If the Wi-Fi doesn't work, you may need to blacklist the in-tree module.

Comment: I installed the driver and blacklist the older one but it doesn't help:&

Comment: @YiTian  It looks like you didn't blacklist the rtwpci driver.

Comment: It seems I blacklisted rtwpci,I changed the name to rtw_pci now it doesn't appear. I also make install again the new driver after upgrade. Now it works! thanks a lot! @heynnema